# how to let item scroll to top of the Recycleview when using LinelayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset?first time not effect

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

i want to let the recycleview item scroll to top by click one button.and i use
 `lineLayoutManger.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position,0);` 
the position is i want to scroll item postion.but when i go into the Activity and have init the adapter.but when i click the buttton to let fifth item scroll to top. but it just on bottom of the screen. if i click the button again it show normal the fifth item is on top.the items are not the same height.
whate should i do.i have search many article.but have no answer.thanks    the wrong effect picture[see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rCRJ.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get linearLayoutManager from your recyclerView List like this:

```
((LinearLayoutManager) mList.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(mPositionToScroll, 0);
```

Comment: i do this,but it still not effect,the first time item just can be visible it on tottom of scroll.the recycleview have a header and the item is Imageview Load by Glide

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know the way you define your recyclerview

Comment: code`topLayoutManger = new TopLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(topLayoutManger);
        mRecyclerView.addHeaderView(mVHeader);
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
        mProductDetailAdapter = new ProductDetailAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        mProductDetailAdapter.setListener(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mProductDetailAdapter);`

Comment: xml `<ExRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_product_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/title_bar_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/product_detail_bottom_menu_height"/>`